# Не срабатывает обработчик прокрутки JS

Tags: javascript, html, прокрутка

Такая проблема, не срабатывает обработчик прокрутки страницы во время скролла, но если используется навигация якорями, то все отлично работает. Никаких ошибок в консоль не выдает
Заранее спасибо

#### html

```
<nav>
    <a href="#about" >О нас</a>
    <a href="#types">Виды работ</a>
    <a href="#our">Наши работы</a>
    <a href="#contactUs">Контакты</a>
</nav>
...

<span id="top" class="anchor"></span>
...
<spanid="about" class="anchor"></span>
...
<span id="types" class="anchor"></span>
...
<span id="our" class="anchor"></span>
...
<span id="contactUs" class="anchor"></span>
```

#### js

```
const navs = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]');
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.anchor');
data = {
    'top': window.pageYOffset + anchors[0].getBoundingClientRect().top,
    'about': window.pageYOffset + anchors[1].getBoundingClientRect().top,
    'types': window.pageYOffset + anchors[2].getBoundingClientRect().top,
    'our': window.pageYOffset + anchors[3].getBoundingClientRect().top,
    'contactUs': window.pageYOffset + anchors[4].getBoundingClientRect().top
}

// Функция, не работающая при прокрутке

heightCheck = (data) => {  
    anchors.forEach((el, i) => {
        if (pageYOffset == data[el.id]){
            console.log(el.id);
            for (let e of navs){
                e.classList.remove('active');
            }
            navs[i].classList.add('active');
        } 
    })
}

// Перемещение по якорям - работает

for (let nav of navs) {
    nav.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        for (let el of navs){
            el.classList.remove('active');
        }
        e.preventDefault();

        const blockID = nav.getAttribute('href').substr(1);

        document.getElementById(blockID).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'start'
        });
        nav.classList.add('active');
    });
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    heightCheck(data);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не забывайте инициализировать переменные:

```
const data = {
    'top': window.pageYOffset + anchors[0].getBoundingClientRect().top,
    'about': window.pageYOffset + anchors[1].getBoundingClientRect().top,
    'types': window.pageYOffset + anchors[2].getBoundingClientRect().top,
    'our': window.pageYOffset + anchors[3].getBoundingClientRect().top,
    'contactUs': window.pageYOffset + anchors[4].getBoundingClientRect().top
}
```

По функции: вы подсовывайте forEach не массив, а NodeList. Либо преобразовывайте для начала Nodelist в массив, либо используйте для этого следующею конструкцию:

```
let heightCheck = (data) => {  
    [].forEach.call(anchors, (el, i) => {
        if (window.pageYOffset == data[el.id]){
            console.log(el.id);
            for (let e of navs){
                e.classList.remove('active');
            }
            navs[i].classList.add('active');
        } 
    })
}
```

Comment: Все, разобрался. Спасибо за помощь